# Create a method called filter that has two string parameters and returns a string

Tags: java, string

The method will filter out all occurrences of the second string from the first sting. The filter is case sensitive. Do not filter out cat if the second argument is CAT.

```
public static void main(String[] args){        // should filter out the   
  System.out.println("method: filter");       // second string
  System.out.println(filter( "CS221 is terrible", "terrible"));
  System.out.println(filter( "my cat is a nice cat", "cat"));
  System.out.println(filter( "ababababa","ab"));
  System.out.println(filter( "not here", "a"));
  System.out.println(filter( "abababab","ab"));
  System.out.println(filter( "CATcatCAT","CAT"));
  System.out.println(filter( "dark","k"));
  System.out.println(filter("ususerer", "user"));
}
public static String filter ( String str, String filter){
  String temp = "";
  int i = 0;

  while(i < str.length() && str.indexOf(filter,i) != -1){                                            
     if(str.indexOf(filter,i)!=-1){
         temp+=str.substring(i, str.indexOf(filter,i));
     }else{
         temp+=str.substring(i,str.length());
     }
     i = str.indexOf(filter, i)+ filter.length();
     i++;
  }
  return temp;

}
```

> Output of the code

```
 CS221 is 
 my is a nice 
 b

 b
 at
 dar
 us
```

> Expected output

```
 CS221 is 
 my is a nice
 a
 not here
 nothing prints at all on this line its just blank
 cat
 dar
 user
```

Comment: `firstString.replace(secondString, "");`

Comment: so how would i implement that into my code?

Comment: Again: `public static String filter (String str, String filter){ return str.replace(filter, "");}`

Comment: Thanks bro it worked!

Comment: This looks like a homework question to show knowledge of loops; therefore use of `replace` or `replaceAll` probably won't get you many marks, unless the exercise is meant to see how well you know the API. Doesn't the question explain what is required?

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly fine.

```
     public static void main(String[] args){        // should filter out the   
     System.out.println("method: filter");       // second string
     System.out.println(filter( "CS221 is terrible", "terrible"));
     System.out.println(filter( "my cat is a nice cat", "cat"));
     System.out.println(filter( "ababababa","ab"));
     System.out.println(filter( "not here", "a"));
     System.out.println(filter( "abababab","ab"));
     System.out.println(filter( "CATcatCAT","CAT"));
     System.out.println(filter( "dark","k"));
     System.out.println(filter("ususerer", "user"));
     }
  public static String filter ( String str, String filter)
  {
     String temp = "";
     int i = 0;
     if(str.indexOf(filter,i) == -1)
     {
        return temp;
     }
   else
   {
       return str.replace(filter,"");
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you're reinventing the wheel...

```
public static String filter (String str, String filter)
    return str.replaceAll(" ?" + filter, "");
}
```

You need to use regex to get the optional leading space, which turns:

```
"my cat is a nice cat" // input
"my is a nice"         // output correct as per your question
```

If you use plain replacement, ie `str.replace(filter, "")`, you get this effect:

```
"my cat is a nice cat" // input
"my  is a nice "       // incorrect: notice the double spaces
```

Comment: You probably could do with `Pattern.quote` in case the filter string contains any special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use `replaceAll`

```
public static String filter(String str, String filter) {
    return str.replaceAll(filter, "").replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ");
}
```